# styling numbers with another font

Tags: css

I have a web page with a custom font in Arabic but numbers with that font appear in Arabic and not clear so I want to show it with Arial font (numbers only)?

**I used that but not working :**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  src: local("Arial"), local("Arial");
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to name your unicode-range specific font.

In sort I am instructing the browser to use `test` font for all applied glyphs, then fallback to `Ballet`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ballet&display=swap');

@font-face {
  font-family:  'test';
  src: local("Arial");
  font-style: normal;
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}


p {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: test, 'Ballet', cursive;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi there! 1 2 3 4 5</p>
```

Comment: I use a custom font for the page but need a specific font to only any numbers on page?

Comment: So in your body (?) tag I would add something like: `font-family: test, myCustomFont`

Comment: It works well with firefox but chrome no, as I am using the latest ver as should be supported ?!

Comment: I tested the attached snippet on Chrome, so I am not sure what your problem is

Answer (score 1):

If I [understand correctly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) you have to set the `unicode-range` to the `@font-face` declaration and then specify the `font-family` for the element (body, ...) where this font should be used:

I created two examples, one with arial and helvetica mixed and one with arial + Comic Sans MS mixed, since this is easier to see.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myNumbers';
  src: local('Arial');
  unicode-range: U+30-39;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.mixed {
  font-family: myNumbers, Helvetica;
}

.mixedComic {
  font-family: myNumbers, 'Comic Sans MS';
}

.arial {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.helvetica {
  font-family: Helvetica
}
```

```html
<p class="mixed">
  Hello, I am 123 and 456 with Arial for Numbers and Helvetica for Text
</p>

<p class="mixedComic">
  Hello, I am 123 and 456 with Comic Sans MS as Text and Arial for Numbers
</p>

<p class="arial">
  Hello, I am 123 and 456 in arial only
</p>

<p class="helvetica">
  Hello, I am 123 and 456 in helvetica only
</p>
```